# How to get a list of instance variables per a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, instance-variables

So I have run into a bug on my Rails 4 page. And the error page looks perfect in Rails, shows all the debugging info on one list.

However I am wondering about writing my own debugging module, and the question would be how to get all instance variables per request?

Or where should I look up the information, something like rails documentation would be perfect.

Comment: This is a very general question. Stack Overflow works better if you have specific questions for us to answer. Can you narrow down the requirements you have? Also explain better: what do you mean by "how to get all instance variables per request?" what variables? where are they coming from? what have you tried to solve it? where's the sticking point for you? can you show us code?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to write your own debugging module (unless you really want to!), as [the Pry Repl](http://pryrepl.org/) does a fantastic job of this. You can even use a gem like [Better Errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) to get a Pry Repl open in your browser, with the stack that your error popped up on.

In any case, the method to get instance variables for any Object in ruby is `instance_variable_get` - more info is available via the [ruby api](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get).